# Filter Date Range - from Date to Date - DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I am relatively new to C#, but learning. I have a DGV with a table called Returns and the Date column is DateOfEntry. I thought setting this up would be rather simple..but I keep getting Operand errors and I am not sure why. I have researched this to no end and have tried various approaches with no luck. Below is the code I am using, could someone explain to me what I may be doing wrong?

Using and Access .mdb file as a DB

```
returnsBindingSource.Filter = ("Select * from Returns where DateOfEntry 
between '"+dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString()+"' and  
'"+dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString()+"'");
```

Comment: You should not assign a select statement as `BindingSource.Filter`. It needs a [filter expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx). When you assign a new filter, it will apply on records in your data table which is data source of the bindingsource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not assign a select statement as [`BindingSource.Filter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx). It needs a string filter expression which follows these [expression syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).

In fact it's a client-side filter mechanism which doesn't need a round-trip to data base server to filter data. When you assign a filter expression to `BindingSource.Filter`, the filter will apply on underlying data source, for example on your `DataTable`.

So you should load data in `Load` event of the form, then apply the filter on loaded data in `Click` event of a filter button for example.

Date values should be enclosed within # signs. For example:

```
returnsBindingSource.Filter =
    String.Format("DateOfEntry >= #{0:yyyy/MM/dd}# AND DateOfEntry <= #{1:yyyy/MM/dd}#",
    dateTimePicker1.Value,
    dateTimePicker2.Value);
```

Comment: Reza, That makes perfect sense. Thank you for taking the time to explain the underlying fundamentals of the code. Thanks again for your help.