# DefaultView.RowFilter throws Format Exception with different DateTime formats

Tags: winforms, datetime, cultureinfo, rowfilter, defaultview

I must have a culture which has date format like this dd.mm.yyyy , but when i forward it to row filter like this:

```
myTable.DefaultView.RowFilter="opened_on=#"+datetimepicker1.value.ToShortDateString()+"#"
```

It says that input string is not in valid DateTime format. 
When user has culture with dd/mm/yyyy format without . it works perfectly. 
Anybody knows why?

Comment: Are you sure? This should not work in any way. The correct way to pass a date here is with the format MM/dd/yyyy or MM.dd.yyyy (By the way mm is for minutes, MM is for months)

Comment: @Steve do you know some article that specifies defaultview.rowfilter filter rules?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35963886/3110834

Answer (score 0):

When you want to filter rows of a DataTable using the DefaultView.RowFilter property on a DateTime column, you should always use the general format of the invariant culture. (MM/dd/yyyy) as explained in MSDN for the [Expression property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataColumn_Expression) from the DataColumn class

> All literal expressions must be expressed in the invariant culture
>   locale. When DataSet parses and converts literal expressions, it
>   always uses the invariant culture, not the current culture.

This could easily verified with something like this

```
DateTime t = new DateTime(2018,12,9);

// will find rows with date = September, 12 2018 
// or will fail if your date is 13/12/2018
// string fmt = t.ToShortDateString();


string fmt = t.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy");
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ADateColumn = #" + fmt + "#";
```